# Itunes Connect Update App Didn't show up in app store

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have made a app and upload to itunes connect pass the apple test and ready for sale.
After a week i made an new version.So open itunes connect create a new version build my app with a new version.and upload to itunes connect .then again new version pass the apple test and ready for sale.Thats it.Then when i saw ready for sale I open my app store from my iphone check my app.But still label say "open"
see i have the app on phone.i was expecting it to say "update".So what did i miss?
Waiting all your help :(

Comment: Do you have automatic update activated? Updates can take up to 48hrs to appear on the store.

Answer (score 0):

As per apple documentation [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html)

**Your app version will then be live on the store pending the customary processing times** usually it takes 24 hours to reflect.